# Excel formula needed

Tags: excel, indexing, match

i have a sheet with the following data: (see below)
Given: the list of locations with the accepted applicants (positive 1) and rejected applicants (negative -1) an the name of the applicant and requisition ID of the applicant.

Problem, I need to create a table that has the same x and y access (location that each applicant applied to). Some Applicants applied to multiple locations (they are highlighted in yellow. Example, Omar applied at location 1 and location 3, thus there is a value of 1 at the intersection of location 1 and location 3, as well as intersection at location 3 and location 1. This allows us to count the number of applicants that have applied to multiple locations.

The total of the green cells should add up to the number of ACCEPTED applicants. This will be used with multiple locations, around 26 and with up to 7000 applicants.

Does anyone have a clue of what formula to use to achieve the results in the table at the top. I have found some success with a "countifs" function for cells in green but have n't had any success with the rest of the table. where there would be a 0 count or null.

I need this formula driven so that we can copy and paste each week the new number of applicants that may vary from 4k to 7k applicants.

any ideas?

[image: Example Image]

Comment: Omar also applied to location 4, is it a typo why it was not picked up in the grid for location 1 and location 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a fairly complicated formula:

```
=IF(B$2=$A3,COUNTIFS($A$14:$A$25,$A3,$B$14:$B$25,1),SUMPRODUCT(($A$14:$A$25=B$2)*COUNTIFS($A$14:$A$25,$A3,$A$14:$A$25,"<>" & $A$14:$A$25,$E$14:$E$25,$E$14:$E$25,$B$14:$B$25,1)))
```

Put that in B3 copy over and down

[image]

Comment: Wow!!! simply Amazing!!! Whatever you do for work, they should give you a raise!! Thank You a million times over!!!

Comment: @f1355b please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.